# Class Synergies in Grand Kingdom

Tags: grand-kingdom

There are plenty of classes in Grand Kingdom. Are there any synergies that one should consider when creating a group of 4?

It is obvious that there should be something like tank + healer + damage dealer, but what about combinations of specific classes?

At the moment I always use a combination like fighter, medic, hunter, witch...